# What is the meaning of maximum value?

Tags: statistics

Suppose we roll 2 fair dice and let X denote the maximum value of the 2 rolls.Find the distribution, mean and variance of X

Is {6,6} the maximum value of X?
How am I supposed to figure out the distribution from just the maximum value? Is it related to pmf or stuff like that?

Comment: it means $\max\{X_1, X_2\}$, where $X_1$ is the value of the first roll, and $X_2$ is the value of the second roll

Comment: No, if $(6,6)$ is the outcome of the roll, 6 is the maximum value;  if $(4,5)$ is the outcome, 5 is the maximum value, etc. The maximum value is a single integer number, not a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ the result of one dice roll, it is a random variable with law : for $k=1,...,6$, $P(A=k)=1/6$.

Let $B$ an independent copy of $A$, it doesn't mean it's the same result, it is another random variable which represents the same phenomena but independent from $A$. Then you look at the random $X:= \max(A,B)$.

$X$ can also be $1$, or $2$,..., or $6$. Let's find its law.

$P(X=1) = P(\max(A,B) =1)= P(A=B=1) = P(A=1)P(B=1)= 1/36$ because you have independence.

$P(X=2) = P(\max(A,B)= 2) = P(A=2,B=1)+P(A=1,B=2)+P(A=B=2) = 3/36$

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be two rolls and let $Y\lor Z$ be their maximum. Then $$P(X=x)=P(Y\lor Z=x)=\frac{\lvert\{(y,z)\mid y\leq z,\; z=x \quad\text{or}\quad y=x,\; z\leq y \}\lvert}{36}.$$

Using the above formula it is easy to find $P(X=i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 6$.
For example $$P(X=1)=\frac{\lvert\{(1,1)\}\lvert}{36}=\frac{1}{36}$$  while$$P(X=2)=\frac{\lvert\{(1,2), (2,2), (2,1))\}\lvert}{36}=\frac{3}{36}.$$
In general we have the formula $$P(X=i)=\frac{2i-1}{36}.$$
Once you find the distribution you can use the well-known formulas for variance and mean.

Answer (score 0):

There are 36 outcomes of 2 dice.
Use a colored pencil to indenify all where one of the dice is a 6.  How many are there?  11.

Of the remaining How many show a 5?

Can you come up with a formula that describes the number of outcomes for each number?  Does this work?  (It does, but verify it for yourself!)

$P(X=x) = \frac {2x-1}{6^2}$

mean:
$\mu = \sum xP(X=x)= \frac 1{36}$

Variance

$\sigma^2 = (\sum x^2P(X=x)) - \mu^2$

Standard Deviation $= \sigma$

Comment: Your use of the symbol X conflicts how X is defined in the question, please modify.

Answer (score 0):

The table below shows the maximum value corresponding to every pair of rolls. All $36$ outcomes have probability $1/36$.
$$\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&2&3&4&5&6\\
3&3&3&4&5&6\\
4&4&4&4&5&6\\
5&5&5&5&5&6\\
6&6&6&6&6&6\\
\end{matrix}$$

For the mean, form the sum of the values times their frequencies and divide by $36$:

$$m=\frac{1\cdot1+2\cdot3+3\cdot5+4\cdot7+5\cdot9+6\cdot11}{36}.$$

For the variance you can compute the average square and subtract the squared average,

$$v=\frac{1^2\cdot1+2^2\cdot3+3^2\cdot5+4^2\cdot7+5^2\cdot9+6^2\cdot11}{36}-m^2.$$